# How do I configure the menu options in slide menu in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, menu

I have successfully setup a slide menu, but am unable to display the menu options. The menu is empty.

I have searched high and low. I'm unable to find an answer. I have been looking at my code for days and (of course) it looks right to me.

```
class LeftTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var menuTableView: UITableView!

let menuItems = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

    if (tableView(tableView: self.tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 1) == 0 ) {
        let emptyStateLabel = UILabel(frame: tableView.frame)
        emptyStateLabel.text = "At this time, nothing is here."

        tableView.backgroundView = emptyStateLabel
    } else {
        tableView.backgroundView = nil

    }

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Added a background view to the table view
    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "growlTaps.png")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView

    // Remove lines where there aren't cells
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

    // Center and scale background image
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    // Center and scale background image
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    // Set the background color
    tableView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return menuItems.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LeftTableViewControllerCellIdentifier")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        self.sideMenuViewController!.setContentViewController(contentViewController: UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")), animated: true)
        self.sideMenuViewController!.hideMenuViewController()
        break
    case 1:
        self.sideMenuViewController!.setContentViewController(contentViewController:UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AboutViewController")), animated: true)
        self.sideMenuViewController!.hideMenuViewController()
        break
    case 2:
        self.sideMenuViewController!.setContentViewController(contentViewController:UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContactVC")), animated: true)
        self.sideMenuViewController!.hideMenuViewController()
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: Outlets for the tableview.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you saying that your menu table is blank? Have you set data source and delegate for your table view?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - the menu is blank. The delegate and data source are set.

Comment: First put a break point in `cellForRow` function and see if that get called. Then in this function, print out the value of `menuItems[indexPath.row]` to see if it's not an empty string

Comment: Added some breakpoints and the print statement. It doesn't hit the breakpoint nor prints out the menuItems.

Comment: That means data source and delegate is not set. Please show me the code to add them or story board screen shot that links your code with the table view.

Comment: @FangmingNing I have added the images above of the outlets.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I recreated the TableView with a TableView in a ViewController and now I'm good to go!